# How is content "locking" handled in custom components?

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, content

Default core's com_content has a built in system that, when a specific article is being edited by a user, it gets "locked", so no other user can edit it at the same time. If the user closes the window or lets the session expire without properly closing that article (clicking on "save" or "cancel", for example), that content gets "checked" and a lock icon is displayed in the backend next to it, which a superadmin will have to unlock.

**My question is**: how is that added to a custom component that has its own content tables? As far as I've been able to find, it looks to me that as long as you use JTable to manipulate that content, then that comes as a built-in feature for methods in that class... is that right? Or do I need to use something else like JTableContent? Do I need to add something to the tables used to store content (any specific columns)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, but you don't need to go down to `JTable`, if you're following the Joomla way and using `JControllerForm` as the basis for your view controller e.g.

```
class MycomponentControllerMycontent extends JControllerForm {}
```

and using `JModelAdmin` as the basis for you components Model e.g.

```
class MycomponentModelMycontent extends JModelAdmin {}
```

Extending `JControllerForm`, gives you a built-in `edit()` method that sets up your model and table for you, and checks access to the record in question as well as whether the table supports checkouts (by checking that a column `checked_out` exists). If it does, it attempts to `checkout()` the record via the model.

By extending JModelAdmin you inherit it's `getItem()`, `checkIn()` and `checkOut()` methods. As mentioned, the model calls `checkout()` (*which it inherits from `JModelForm`*) and makes sure that in addition to the `checked_out` column your table also has one called `checked_out_time`.

At this point one of two things will happen if either of those columns don't exists, `JModelForm` fakes it and returns `true` (indicating job done). Otherwise, it will grab the current users, and then proceed to attempt the checkout first checking if it's already checked out to another user. At this point if finally calls the `JTable` implementation of `checkOut()` (if you haven't overridden it in with your own table definition which in J3 isn't usually required).

`JTable` performs exactly the same column checks, and if all is good (i.e. has a valid ID) updates the columns `checked_out` and `checked_out_time` for the record being edited.

As a side note, when you `edit()` an item, `getItem()` gets called, it loads the record via a `JTable` (i.e. it does a `getTable()` followed by `load($pk)`. *(At this point `JTable` also triggers your **onBeforeLoad** and **onAfterLoad** events for plugins which is nice)*

The record is returned to your version of `JModelAdmin`, which converts it to a base `stdClass` object (it's used to be a `JObject` in times past). The if the record (now object) contains a `params` column/attribute it converts that to a `JRegistry` object for easy access.

So, you get lots of handy things for free using the Joomla way. :)

Comment: Woha! Thanks a lot cppl! That was a very detailed and clear reply, just the starting point I needed to go ahead knowing I'm standing on solid ground. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You're correct in your assumptions.  You need the table set up with associated logic to accomplish what you're trying to do.

As I am learning Joomla 3+, I've been using [Component Creator](http://component-creator.com) to create an extremely simple component with a single table and just the Joomla feature I'm interested in learning.  The generated code is very good, and is easy to follow without all the complexities of the usual components installed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I found this for Joomla 1.5, not sure if it changed too much for 3.3... http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Using_the_JTable_class#Checkout.2FCheckin

And btw, I'm using CC too :)

Comment: That looks to be about the same thing, so I'd so run with it.  Its one of those things that "just work", so I'm not familiar with the intricacies.